# Error in jQuery concatenate

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to build a laravel url dynamically using jQuery. Code that run in onclick event is as follows:

```
var tt = $(this).val();
var EditUrl = '{{ url("/productionentry/' + tt + '/edit") }}';
console.log(tt + EditUrl);
```

The output in console is

```
11http://localhost/pms/public/productionentry/&#039; + tt + &#039;/edit
```

As you can see, I am getting `tt` instead of its value (11). I am not sure why. I have tried changing single quotes to double and double to single. It doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what is going on here. Laravel allows you to place PHP code in your template, and will parse that on request.

```
var tt = $(this).val();
var EditUrl = '{{ url("/productionentry/' + tt + '/edit") }}';
console.log(tt + EditUrl);
```

when parsed by PHP will become

```
var tt = $(this).val();
var EditUrl = 'http://localhost/pms/public/productionentry/&#039; + tt + &#039;/edit';
console.log(tt + EditUrl);
```

The problem here is that the function url() will replace the single AND double quotes with the HTML characters. So, it would becom quite difficult to have url() return a result that is compatible with your javascript insert of tt. If javascript runs this result, it will write to the console:

```
11http://localhost/pms/public/productionentry/&#039; + tt + &#039;/edit
```

So what could you do? You can insert a placeholder in the URL, which is unique and replaced by javascript with the actual value.

```
var tt = $(this).val();
var EditUrl = '{{ url("/productionentry/:insertID:/edit") }}';
EditUrl = EditUrl.replace(':insertID:', tt);
console.log( EditUrl);
```

which should return

```
http://localhost/pms/public/productionentry/11/edit
```

*note: not tested but I hope you get the idea*

Comment: Its not working. I am getting http://localhost/pms/public/productionentry/:insertID:/edit

Comment: My mistake, i didnt store the updated string in the `EditUrl` variable. This should work.